# Trap outgoing icmpv6 packets on linux using RAW sockets

Tags: linux, networking, icmp, raw-sockets

I am trying to capture incoming as well as outgoing icmpv6 packets going out from a host on Linux. I have written the following program to do it. In this program we can trap the incoming packets and not the outgoing packets. Trapping works fine for icmpv4 packets (the commented part of code) but for icmpv6 packets its a problem. I am not interested in using packet filtering (Berkley Packet Filter) mechanism which is a bit intrusive as compared to the method I have used below. Can you let me know if there is something else which could be used to do this? Or does Linux provide any other mechanism to do this?

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char buf[500];
    struct icmp6_hdr *icmpv6_hdr;
    int  raw_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_ICMPV6);
    //int  raw_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_ICMP);
    if(raw_socket <=0)
    {
        perror("Could not create raw socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        if(recvfrom(raw_socket, buf, 500, 0,NULL,NULL)<0)
        {
            perror("error in recvfrom");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            icmpv6_hdr = (struct icmp6_hdr *)buf;
            switch(icmpv6_hdr->icmp6_type)
            {
                case ND_ROUTER_SOLICIT:
                    printf("ND_ROUTER_SOLICIT");
                    break;
                case ND_ROUTER_ADVERT:
                    printf("ND_ROUTER_ADVERT");
                    break;
                case ND_NEIGHBOR_SOLICIT:
                    printf("ND_NEIGHBOR_SOLICIT");
                    break;
                case ND_NEIGHBOR_ADVERT:
                    printf("ND_NEIGHBOR_ADVERT");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("icmpv6_type:%x\n",icmpv6_hdr->icmp6_type);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library which is meant to capture any network traffic passing through your NIC called PCAP.  It has an internal filter you can configure to match icmpv6.  This is the library that Wireshark and tcpdump use to sniff traffic. http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

If you don't want to be "intrusive" be sure to disable promiscuous mode.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I only know about ICMPv6.
Since ICMPv6 contains so much more messages than ICMPv4, they create a filter sockopt. You can read about the details in the corresponding RFC:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2292#section-3.2

It's all in there. Basically, you have a structure, define a filter mask with some macros and set the socket option.
That only works for IPv6 of course.

Also, you want to create the socket like this:
socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6)